# Can I use ORIENTATION landscape only when video plays in webview?

Tags: java, android

Can I force landscape when video plays in webview and rest of app run on vertical mode? I googled so much unfortunately, I did not find anything.
Here is my code:

```
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            setTitle(view.getTitle());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }

    private class MyChrome extends WebChromeClient {

        private View mCustomView;
        private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
        protected FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;
        private int mOriginalOrientation;
        private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;
        MyChrome() {}

        public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster()
        {
            if (mCustomView == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), 2130837573);
        }

        public void onHideCustomView()
        {
            ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
            this.mCustomView = null;
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
            setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
            this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
        }

        public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback)
        {
            if (this.mCustomView != null)
            {
                onHideCustomView();
                return;
            }
            this.mCustomView = paramView;
            this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
            this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
            this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
            ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code in the beginning seems being incomplete. Without knowing if it's a matter of your issue, I propose to complete it so far that the block with 2 x `@Override` is starting logical (probably a class). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks David I solved this issue, now I'm stuck at updating my app through website out of google play https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227794/can-i-updating-android-app-through-website